# Error when using mongoose.connect on AWS EC2 server

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mongoose

I've installed Node, express, and mongodb all successfully. I can run mongo in my terminal and it starts correctly. I can also see data i've manually stored.

Locally, I was using mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test'); and I had no issues. On my EC2 I used mongoose.connect('mongodb://ipaddress:27017/test'); but it's failing.
**Error: failed to connect to [ipaddress:27017].**

ipaddress is an actual ip address not a string or variable.

> mongo
>   show dbs  <-- this shows my databases so I know it's running!

I've looked online for a few hours and have come up short! I'm sure it's a simple setting i've missed.

On my EC2 i'm allowing all connections on all port ranges. 
What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the mongod instance running on the same server?

Comment: Yes it is. All on the same EC2 server.

Comment: Then the IP addess should be set to either localhost or 0.0.0.0

Comment: That worked! Could you explain why localhost wouldn't work but 0.0.0.0 would?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the mongod instance is running on the same server, you need to set the IP Address to `0.0.0.0`

I'm not sure why this needs to be done, but I got (some) understanding by reading the explanations listed on this [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/78048/whats-the-difference-between-ip-address-0-0-0-0-and-127-0-0-1).